# how to retrieve all stations from a query with many related tables using Laravel Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following query that  retrieves all stations related tables, table estacion(station) has 55 records in total. using the code below i only retrieve records that have data related with other tables only. Whether a station has related data or not I need to display all 55 stations too. I tried query buider with leftJoin, but the query is too huge compared to using Eloquent.

```
  $ficha = Estacion::select('estacion.*')
                        ->with('titular')
                        ->with('operador')
                        ->with('estacionestado')
                        ->with('comuna')
                        ->with('eqestacion')
                        ->with('equipos.parametros')
                        ->where('estacion.id',$value)
                        ->get();
```

what i get now. 
[image]

Comment: Never write other languages in backend except english. What a front end user can't see should always be on english. Reasons: 1. other people can work on that project. 2. it is easier to get help from others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go:

```
$ficha = Estacion::with('titular',
                        'operador',
                        'estacionestado',
                        'comuna',
                        'eqestacion',
                        'equipos.parametros')
                        ->where('id',$value)
                        ->get();
```

This will give all stations with related data. Where `estacion.id / id` equals `$value`

If this doesn't work either you're comparing on wrong `$value` else your relationships aren't setup correctly.

Comment: It returns exactly the same data, 1 station plus the related table data, most  stations have neither related data in titular nor operador for now.

Comment: @RodrigoCabrera That doesn't matter it will always return all stations even if the relationship data is empty.